# audit review trap: link doesn't show the answer you should review

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-audits

I fell recently in the following (late answer) audit trap: Instead of reading the answer in the review queue I clicked on the link and read there the (only) answer. Since it looked pretty similar and the points where equal I went back, voted the good question up and failed the audit: the test was about a deleted answer... My request is now to avoid such traps as already deleted answers or to give the link to a page, where the answer still exists.

Comment: Good lord, they're both in English even!

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a trap. This is you not paying enough attention. The review queue provided you with a post to review and buttons to click related to that specific post. You decided not to use that tool.

If you are leaving the queue to get more context, you need to pay attention.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11319302) is the audit you failed:

> Reliable transfers are what's important and the add-on that it does the advancement of error checking seems sufficient to toggle the amount of bits per packet or segment especially if the frame is read and delivered without TCP and in sequence with the fewer bits. It pays to receive something quality and another good question to ask is whether those bits are randomly arranging other parts of the network to another device or are you saying it takes all 1's and time consuming arrangement of a packet or segment to deliver CRC?

Whether it *looks* similar or not to the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356447/189134) answer, isn't relevant. It *clearly* is not the same post.

---

The solution to your problem: Slow down and read the post you are presented in the queue. If you leave the queue for more context, make sure you are still reading the same post.

Comment: I am not complaining that a fell in the trap. I might even deserved this for not comparing the two answers on different sides. It is just a little bit annoying for reviewers always to check, if they are in an audit or not (this shouldn't be even possible!) because then things behave differently from what they should. There just shouldn't be a difference in the normal review flow when an audit comes.